# addScriptDeclaration is not working

Tags: javascript, joomla-4.x, system-plugin

I am trying to add an inline Javascript in my Joomla 4 plugin using addScriptDeclaration().I edited the code like suggested but the plugin is not working .After enabling it , it is not doing anything .Also I'm confused about the error **Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined**

```
 <?php
// no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

use Joomla\CMS\Factory;
use Joomla\CMS\Plugin\CMSPlugin;

class PlgSystemhelloworld extends CMSPlugin
{
  
  public function onAfterDispatch()
    {
   $result = "girl";
  $document = JFactory::getDocument();
  $document->addScriptDeclaration(' document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function()
    {
      alert(hello + "' . $result . '");
      }
   );');
      
     
    
    } 
}
?>
```

Also, Is there any good tutorials available ?

Comment: Welcome to JSE, Devika.  Please take our [tour] while you wait for support.  Are you able to show us the rendered source code that is generated (by [edit]ing your question)?  We might need to see all of the rendered JQuery scripting that the page contains.

Comment: As an aside, might a css solution also work (perhaps in a less verbose fashion)? https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/

Comment: I see in your similar question on stack overflow that you try to use this short script in a custom plugin and I am also not sure that your plugin itself works, so if you need more help regarding that just extend your question with some added info/code regarding that plugin code and we can give you more help on that too here. So even if the code in my answer correct and works, your plugin still can have some issues and you will not see the correct result.

Comment: As you updated your question we should see wether your plugin works or not. Please check in your “page source” if you see the intended script included in your page `<head>` or not and get back to me with the answer. How to check your page source in different browsers: https://neilpatel.com/blog/how-to-read-source-code/

Comment: If you see the short script included in the `<head>` of your page it means that your plugin works. Then we can move further...

Comment: @Zollie No Sir , the script is not present in the <head> tag . The code was there in the page source code when I was using `window.event` .But since it is deprecated I changed it .  What should I do next ?

Comment: and if you change your function name to `public function onBeforeCompileHead()` ?

Comment: Yes!!! I got it .Thankyou so much sir :) I have been trying to make this for like weeks.Thankyou so much

Comment: Good job! :) Your welcome. Thanks also to @Sharky who pointed to the correct plugin events for your plugin.

Comment: Let's see that this page is appropriately resolved by an answer instead of a comment.  I see that Zollie's answer has been updated to reflect what has been mentioned in comments.  Please either award the green tick to Zollie's answer or post your own new/unique answer and accept that.  It is important to the system and researchers that resolved pages have an accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*$document->addScriptDeclaration()* method is working, no problem with that.

`window.event` is deprecated:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event

instead of that you should use **document.addEventListener()** or **window.addEventListener()** on the event of `DOMContentLoaded`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event

So the working version of your code is about this:

```
<?php
// no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

use Joomla\CMS\Factory;
use Joomla\CMS\Plugin\CMSPlugin;

class PlgSystemappendtext extends CMSPlugin
{
    public function onBeforeCompileHead()
    {
       $result = " girl"; // just for a sample text
       $document = JFactory::getDocument();
       $document->addScriptDeclaration(' window.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", function()
       {
             alert(hello + "' . $result . '"); //or any other js code
       }
       ); ');
     }
}
```

The `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` is coming from another wrongly applied jQuery script on your page.

And after few question's update and clearing just to complete this for future readers, as @Sharky correctly pointed to the appropriate plugin events, the plugin should use `public function onBeforeCompileHead()` function and everything will work fine.

Comment: @Devika Harshan - I'm sorry, I left out the double quote in the js code, I corrected that...

Comment: @Devika Harshan - Of course the code would work without the double quote too if the `$result` variable was a number which I was not sure of, that is why I corrected that...

Comment: thankyou for the reply sir

Answer (score 2):

You are using `onAfterRender` event which is not suitable for modifying the document object because this event is triggered after the page has already been rendered. Use `onAfterDispatch`, `onBeforeRender` or `onBeforeCompileHead` instead.

Comment: Thankyou sir ,I got it .Like you said I was using the wrong event.